# Does Apple's mandatory 64-bit build mean all apps will be twice their original size?

Tags: ios

From June 1, Apple makes it mandatory that all apps and updates support 64-bit.

So does that mean that Download Size of each app will be twice as big if developer want his app to support devices older than iPhone 5s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the size of a application come from its assets (images, films, database, etc) with the new slice tool that apple is offering it will actually make the apps much smaller as you won't need to download assets from different screens as you would had before
Also change the application from 64bits to 32bits shouldn't change the size of the application per say, it could create more allocation of memory from when the app is running as the pointers would use 64bits instead 32bits, that that is actually all.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that your binary will be twice as big. It's true that your code instructions are now 64 bits. Code is small compare to assets in your IPA which remains to be the same size.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused because the "App Store size estimate" tells me the IPA is almost twice as big.

Comment: If your app is mainly code, with no large assets (images, audio, video, etc.) then yes, it'll be about twice as big as a 32-bit only app.